# Get The Weeks For a Given Date Range and Get Datas for the weeks (MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I need a query that lists weeks of a given date range and weeks must be calculated from the calendar and not from any column in the table. Then with the dates of the week i need to get the total counts of id for the weeks. I use this query to get the weeks

```
select * from (select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date from
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
(select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
(select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
(select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v 
where selected_date between '2017-04-13' and '2017-07-12' group by WEEK(ADDDATE(selected_date,1)) order by selected_date asc
```

Then with the **date ranges** i get the total counts of id for each weeks  and *if there is no id* for a week then i give the count as 0 by the below query

```
SELECT sum1, sum2 FROM 
(SELECT count(id) AS sum1 FROM vqn_list 
WHERE ( sl_posted_date BETWEEN ( '2017-05-01' ) AND ( '2017-05-10' ) )) AS T1 
JOIN (SELECT count(id) AS sum2 FROM vqn_list
 WHERE ( sl_posted_date BETWEEN ( '2017-05-11' ) AND ( '2017-05-20' ) )) AS T2
```

***Table Structure:***

```
| id        | sl_posted_date
-------------------------------
| 1         | 2017-05-01
| 2         | 2017-05-03
| 3         | 2017-05-04
| 4         | 2017-05-06
| 5         | 2017-05-08
| 6         | 2017-05-015
...
```

I need to get The Results as:

```
| selected_date          | counts
-----------------------------------
| 2017-04-8              | 45
| 2017-04-15             | 65
| 2017-04-22             | 489
| 2017-04-29             | 7852
| 2017-05-06             | 50
```

The query comes so big with date ranges. Is it possible to join the both queries to one? I have a data like 2 million for like 3 years so the second query is so slow. Please Help me to join the queries as i am not so good in MYSQL queries.

Comment: Please don't tag MySQL questions with SQL Server.  These are two different systems.  Often they require different solutions.

Comment: ok thanks for the suggestion.